# Excel Solver for demand with tiered pricing

Tags: excel, solver, nonlinear-optimization

I am using Excel Solver to allocate demand across several suppliers. I am using tiered pricing, so the objective function is nonlinear. (price is function of volume, and total cost = price x volume). However, when I run the solver, it gives me a solution but it is not the most optimal solution. I am thinking the reason is because I am using the wrong method or because I use a lot of iferror functions.

1. There shouldn't be any breaks in my objective function, so I should use GRG Nonlinear correct? My objective function is (total cost = V1xP1 + V2xP2... , where V1 is volume of supplier 1 and P1 is price of supplier 1. Price varies based on volume but it is tiered (ie. first 100kg is $1, second 400kg is $.95 etc).)
2. I use iferror functions in all of my price calculations. This is to prevent any #DIV/0! errors when the volume is 0.

Also, this is the formula I use to calculate avg unit price based on tiered pricing.

```
=SUMPRODUCT( --(E$135 > E$10:E$11), E$135-E$10:E$11, E$3:E$4-E$2:E$3)/E$135

where E$135 = demand, E$10:E$11 = tiered price volume, E$3:E$4 = tiered prices
```

Does anyone know if either of these two would cause an issue with solver? Right now it runs without errors, but it does not output the optimal solution. Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: I read that GRG Nonlinear will only give you the local optimal solution, not the global optimal solution. Is there anyway I could find the global optimal solution for a nonlinear objective function?

Comment: I think this is piecewise linear (linear for each segment). These type of models are often modeled as a Mixed Integer Programming model (Solver calls this Simplex).

Comment: Is there any excel add-ins that you would recommend for this?

Comment: I always believe the first step is to develop a proper optimization model and collecting representative data. After that selecting a solver and implementing the model is much easier.